# How to draw a line on a bitmap in Stage3D using Agal?

Tags: actionscript, stage3d, agal

How can I draw a line on a bitmap in Stage3D using Agal? Can someone provide a code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently wrote a simple library to draw lines on Stage3D.
It's called Zebroid, https://github.com/luwes/Zebroid

Zebroid does not support line caps or joints yet.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Starling you can try this:

```
/**
 * Class Line
 * @author Leandro Barreto 2012
 * @version 1.0
 **/

package starling.utils
{
    import starling.display.Quad;
    import starling.display.Sprite;

    public class Line extends Sprite
    {
        private var baseQuad:Quad;
        private var _thickness:Number = 1;
        private var _color:uint = 0x000000;

        public function Line()
        {
            baseQuad = new Quad(1, _thickness, _color);
            addChild(baseQuad);
        }

        public function lineTo(toX:int, toY:int):void
        {
            baseQuad.width = Math.round(Math.sqrt((toX*toX)+(toY*toY)));
            baseQuad.rotation = Math.atan2(toY, toX);
        }

        public function set thickness(t:Number):void
        {
            var currentRotation:Number = baseQuad.rotation;
            baseQuad.rotation = 0;
            baseQuad.height = _thickness = t;
            baseQuad.rotation = currentRotation;
        }

        public function get thickness():Number
        {
            return _thickness;
        }

        public function set color(c:uint):void
        {
            baseQuad.color = _color = c;
        }

        public function get color():uint
        {
            return _color;
        }
    }
}
```

Someone suggested at the Starling forums that we create a Line class which draws a few quads connecting two points.  This tutorial shows how to create polygons using AGAL for shaders:

http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/custom_display_objects